# How to detect if an other front-end post/page is in HTTPS/SSL from admin to display a notice?

Tags: custom-post-types, ssl, https

I'm making a plugin which generate a form in a custom post. For security, I would like to avise the administrator with a notice if this specific post does not work with HTTPS/SSL yet.

I know the function **is_ssl()** but it is to check the current page, not a specific post by the ID.

Someone has got an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution :

In my **Admin object**

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'display_warning_no_ssl') );

function display_warning_no_ssl() {

    $forms = foo_get_form_pages();

    foreach ( $forms as $form ){
        $permalink = get_post_permalink( $form['ID'] );
        $protocol = foo_get_protocol( $permalink );
        if($protocol !== "https"){
            ?>
            <div class="notice error is-dismissible" >
                <p><?php _e( 'Enabling the HTTPS protocol for the page : "'.$permalink.'" is not mandatory but strongly advised for security issues for your users.!', PLUGIN_DOMAIN ); ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }

}
```

In my **helpers.php**

```
function foo_get_form_pages(){
    global $wpdb;
    $forms_query_string       = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type='foo'";
    $forms = $wpdb->get_results( $forms_query_string, ARRAY_A );
    $f_forms = array();
    foreach ( $forms as $key => $val ){
        $f_forms[$val['post_name']] = $val; 
    }
    return $f_forms; 
}

function foo_get_protocol( $url ){
    $a_url = explode("://", $url);
    return $a_url[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get all posts/pages, check if the shortcode for your plugin is used, and if so retrieve the permalink for that post/page.

Other than that, I don't know of any reliable method. And while I think your intentions are good, this does not really belong in your plugin, it isn't really your job to educate people.